# How tensorflow uses GPU memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I want to train a DNN on my Nvidia GTX 950 (2GB) using Cuda 10.0 with a large dataset (25GB).
I want to know how tensorflow use the dataset, because I get a 'CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory' when I try to start the training, even if I divided it in small batches (with batch size = 2).
I added this code snippet to train in GPU:

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import set_session
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True  # dynamically grow the memory used on the GPU
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
set_session(sess)  # set this TensorFlow session as the default session for Keras
```

I want to know how tensorflow works on GPU.
I mean, it tries to upload a single batch, train and then upload another batch (clearing the previous batch on GPU memory) or it tries to bring all the dataset on the GPU memory.
Because I don't know how to solve this problem of memory, I think I set the smaller batch size but it still not work.
I suppose that tensorflow tries to allocate the whole dataset on GPU, I need to prevent this. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Please let us know the `TensorFlow` and `Keras` version you are using. Please check this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and verify that you have followed all the steps properly to enable `GPU setup` in your system. Thank you.